# PHP Version: 7.3.12

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel project show lowest version.

C:\wamp64\www\vstconstruction_backend>php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 15:10:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: That `>php -v` should fail, so it shows that you have added one of the PHP versions to your Windows PATH. You should never do that with WAMPServer as it causes these sort of issues

Comment: See the duplicate and create a batch file you can run when you want to associate any version of PHP with the CLI you have installed in WAMPServer (there can be many)